# Angular 2 rxjs observables created from BehaviorSubject are not working with forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am trying to use `Observable.forkJoin` and the subscribe handler is never getting hit. The forkJoin operator is working for me in other parts of my app and the only difference I can think of in the non-working scenario is that the observables are being created from `BehaviorSubject` objects using its `asObservable()` function.

This subscribe gets hit

```
    let obs = Observable.of(1);

    Observable.forkJoin(
        obs
    ).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This one does not

```
    let bs = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
    let obs = bs.asObservable();

    Observable.forkJoin(
        obs
    ).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Of course in my real use case there is more than one obseravble which is why I'm using forkJoin in the first place.

Is there something else that needs to be done to BehaviorSubject to make it work with forkJoin?

UPDATE:

After investigating the RxJs docs a bit more I realized that the `Observable.combineLatest` was much better suited to my need than `forkJoin`... Link here in case any comes across this SO post: 
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that `forkJoin` joins the observables when they complete.

In your first snippet, you are creating an observable using `of` - which, upon `subscribe`, immediately emits a value and then completes.

In your second snippet, the `BehaviorSubject` does not complete. If you were to call `complete`, you would see the value logged to the console:

```
let bs = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
let obs = bs.asObservable();

Observable.forkJoin(
    obs
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});

bs.complete();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After investigating the RxJs docs a bit more I realized that the `Observable.combineLatest` was much better suited to my need than `forkJoin`... Link here in case any comes across this SO post: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest

Answer (score 0):

You can use take(1) pipe if you don't want to use complete method.

```
const subjectA = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
const a$ = subjectA.asObservable();

Observable.forkJoin(
    a$.pipe(take(1))
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```